# copying columns from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am encountering

> run time error 9
>
> subscript out of range

Here is my code:

```
Sub copydatatocreatereport()

Dim report As Workbook
Dim datafile As Variant

'report is the active workbook where I want data to paste
'datafile is workbook which has data I want to copy from
    
datafile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If datafile = "false" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open datafile

Workbooks("datafile").Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("a").Copy _
    Destination:=Workbooks("report").Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("a1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a workbook called `report`?  Or did you mean to `Set report = ThisWorkbook` (or similar) in this code somewhere?  If so, then Destination would be `Report.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("a")` rather than `Workbooks("report")`

Comment: @VBnewBee the copy line should be `Workbooks(datafile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Copy _
    Destination:=report.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")` , but you need to `Set report = ThisWorkbook` or something similar

Comment: @Dave yes, i have workbook called report where i am running this code., thanks a lot for suggesting Set report = ThisWorkbook, should work now

Comment: @Dave of course, had to change columns a1 to a thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `datafile` as workbook (to the workbook you are trying to open).

You need to set `report` to `ActiveWorkbook` (not recommended, better to use `ThisWorkbook` , where the code lies, or a specific workbook).

You can't paste Entire Column to a specific cell.

```
Sub copydatatocreatereport()

Dim report          As Workbook
Dim datafile        As Workbook
Dim wbPath          As String

'report is the active workbook where i want data to paste
Set report = ActiveWorkbook  ' safer to have a name of Workbook or use ThisWorkbook (where this code lies)

wbPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
If wbPath = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No Workbook was selected", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If

' set datafile to Open workbook which I want to copy from
Set datafile = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
datafile.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Copy Destination:=report.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note this is untested, but should point you in the right direction

```
Sub copydatatocreatereport()
Dim Report As Workbook
Dim ReportPath As String

'Report is the workbook where I want to paste data. We want report to be the destination - we do not need to create an object for the currently open workbook
'ReportPath is the string used to open the Report workbook

'Allow the user to select a workbook string
ReportPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
'Exit if nothing is selected
If ReportPath = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set Report object = to the selected workbook. This was missing previously
Set Report = Workbooks.Open(ReportPath)

'Paste column a from the currently open workbook to the desistination workbook
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("a").Copy _
    Destination:=Report.Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("a")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't copy to `.Columns("a1")`; you'll get a 1004 object error.  Should be to `.Columns("a")` instead...

Comment: @Jiminy, thanks mate, although this is exporting data from report to datafile, i managed to reverse it after modifying

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- use Workbooks(datafile) instead of Workbooks("datafile")
- have datafile purged of the not-sheet name characters

As follows:

```
    Dim name As String

    datafile = Application.GetOpenFilename

    Workbooks.Open datafile

    name = Right(datafile, Len(datafile) - InStrRev(datafile, "\"))

     Workbooks(name).Worksheets("sheet1")....
```

Comment: Again, you can't copy `.Columns("a")` to `.Columns("a1")`...  A1's not a column.  Destination needs to be `.Columns("a")` to avoid the 1004 object error

Comment: @Dave, thank you for your comment. I just copied/pasted that last statement just to make it clear where to place 'name', which is the only purpose if my answer. So I didn't check the remaining part of it: I'll remove the left part of that statement.